# How to draw 2D animation and update it dynamically by the user?

Tags: java, android, click, draw, geometry

I am new to android. Sorry if this question is very silly... 
 I am trying to create a simple app. 
The rule is .. whenever i touch or click a button which is located at the center, the radius of circle should get increased. And whenever i stopped clicking , then the radius of the circle should be reduced slowly. Here i created a circle, but i can't update it. I used button click listner and onTouchListner but nothing works... Please help me to do this app... Thank you so much for your help..

```
public class TestcircleActivity extends Activity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button b;
    int clicks = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

    }

    public class MyView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

    }

}
```